# Sort child row data and move parent along with child group

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr class="parent">
        <th id="apple">Apple</th>
        <th id="orange">Orange</th>
        <th>Banana</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent">
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>Orange</td>
        <td>Banana</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td>Apple 1</td>
        <td>Orange 1</td>
        <td>Banana 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td>Apple 2</td>
        <td>Orange 2</td>
        <td>Banana 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent">
        <td>Table</td>
        <td>cHAIR</td>
        <td>Mouse</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td>Table 1</td>
        <td>cHAIR 1</td>
        <td>Mouse 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td>Table 2</td>
        <td>cHAIR 2</td>
        <td>Mouse 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to sort only child row data onclick of `<th>` and move parent tr along with the child tr. I am unable to do this as it's only one table.

The code I am using currently is: [demo of code](http://jsfiddle.net/coonooo/syYgP)

Comment: And I suppose you want to sort by the parent value in that column?

Answer (score 0):

I think I now understand what you want. I think you want to sort the groups among each other, by using the parent, and also sort the children within the group.

```
$('th').click(function() {
    //remove and group
    var groups = [];
    $(this).parent().siblings().each(function() {
        $(this).detach();
        if($(this).hasClass('parent')) {
            groups.push({parent:$(this), children:[]});
        } else {
            groups[groups.length-1].children.push($(this));
        }
    });

    //sort, inter-group, and intra-group
    var i = $(this).index();
    function compareRows(rowA, rowB) {
        var a = $(rowA.children()[i]).text();
        var b = $(rowB.children()[i]).text();
        return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
    }
    groups.sort(function(groupA, groupB) {
        return compareRows(groupA.parent, groupB.parent);
    });
    $.each(groups, function(_, group) {
        group.children.sort(compareRows);
    });

    //reinsert
    var table = $(this).parent().parent();
    $.each(groups, function(_, group) {
        table.append(group.parent).append(group.children);
    });
});
```

Please clarify if your intent was other.

Comment: i haven't check your code in mine but as per your comment, this code is sorting parent data and moving children with parent.. but I need I want to sort child row data and want to move along prev()+closest() tr with this. I think it does not make sense. is that possible.. ?

Comment: So what happens when one child is first and the other is last? Where does the parent go?

Comment: please suggest what is the best possible way to sort children and move their parent with them before very first children as per group.

Comment: I cannot, until you answer the question in my previous comment.

Comment: suppose by default data is like this: parent > 45 > 30 > 60 > 15. after sorting i want it to be like : parent > 15 > 30 > 45 > 60. is that make sense.. ?

Comment: It's not working and don't even understand your code. can you try this in fiddle?

Comment: I fixed a bug. See http://jsfiddle.net/z8c9Y/. Note that the sort is the default Javascript sort (case-sensitive, capitals before lowercase).

Comment: its working in fiddle but only once. i need it ascending and descending both.

Comment: Ah, well it would have helped to mention that in your question, no?

Comment: yes, thanks for your support. I would really appreciate if you do it as ascending and descending both.